# How to observe events that happening in "new mail" page fields in OWA?

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I need to listen to the onChange event of input fields (To:, Cc:, subject, body etc.) on the new email page and to change the UI in my add-in. There is a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Share the code part, you'd tried.

Comment: I can't share the code, but I've tried to add async handler to mailbox to detect any of changes
```Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged)```
but it doesn't work. It doesn't trigger on any actions on the page

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemChanged` event is used to handle scenarios when users switch to different items when leveraging [Pinnable Taskpane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane). It is not designed to send an event for changes to the same item.

The API you are asking for is not implemented today. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10315167-provide-an-event-to-let-outlook-add-in-respond-to).
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing request. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.